# Parallel.ForEach fails with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, task-parallel-library

Very simple `Parallel.ForEach` call sometimes fails with a

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

exception somewhere in the library and not in my code. Here is the stack trace.

```
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskReplicator.Run[TState](ReplicatableUserAction`1 action, ParallelOptions options, Boolean stopOnFirstFailure)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.PartitionerForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](Partitioner`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 simpleBody, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ThrowSingleCancellationExceptionOrOtherException(ICollection exceptions, CancellationToken cancelToken, Exception otherException)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.PartitionerForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](Partitioner`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 simpleBody, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 body)
...
```

It occurs very rarely and I have seen it happen only couple of times on .NET Core 2.1 App on Linux with no visible reason and no way to reproduce.

Here is my simplified code:

```
var chunkSize = 100;
var processingList = new List<int>();

// removed code here which fill the processing list with data. No nulls here for sure

Parallel.ForEach(
    ChunkIndexes(processingList.Count, chunkSize),
    (interval) =>
    {
        var worker = new MyWorker();
        worker.Process(processingList, interval.startIndex, interval.endIndex);
    });
```

```
// Function called by Parallel.ForEach()
public static IEnumerable<(int startIndex, int endIndex)> ChunkIndexes(int totalCount, int chunkSize)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < totalCount; i += chunkSize)
    {
        yield return (i, Math.Min(i + chunkSize, totalCount));
    }
}
```

The code in `Parallel.ForEach` is working on different pieces of the list and is only modifying values but not changing the list size in any way.
There is no async/await code, no file access, no network calls either. It looks very simple and I just cannot figure out how it could ever fail for any reason. Any ideas?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and step through the code. Somewhere there's a null object on which you try to access a property or method. From the code presented, it would be `processingList`.

Comment: It is not that simple. There is checking for null or empty list just before Parallel.ForEach. I also have not seen this problem happen on windows. Only on linux and only couple of times in a month or so. This code runs at least few hundred times a day without problems.

Comment: It is possible that you have found a bug in the TPL. But as a side note I should point out two peculiarities of your code. (1) The `ChunkIndexes` method re-invents the built-in `Partitioner.Create(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive, int rangeSize)`. (2) the `List` class is not thread-safe, and by updating it from multiple threads concurrently you are breaking the guarantees offered by the manufacturer of the class. I would not file a bug report to Microsoft based on code that doesn't play by the rules.

Comment: It was easier to write my own ChunkIndexes method than to find an already existing function. I also have almost identical old code that always works. That code has MaxDegreeOfParallelism limited to the number of processors and it may be a more complex and thus slower code. Maybe my new code is too fast?

Comment: Based on your StackTrace and based on the source code of [TaskReplicator.Run](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6072e4d3a7a2a1493f514cdf4be75a3d56580e84/src/libraries/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskReplicator.cs#L132) either the `options` is null or the replicator's `_pendigReplicas`

Comment: I think that `_pendingReplicas` cannot be null as it is static readonly property and other successful call to Parallel.ForEach is already finished before the failed one. This leaves only `options` as a possible null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on other uses of Parallel.ForEach in my own code, the failure stack trace, and the comment below I did a small code change. Everything looks good so far.

> Based on your StackTrace and based on the source code of TaskReplicator.Run either the options is null or the replicator's _pendigReplicas – Peter Csala Aug 27 at 14:48

Here is the original source code that could fail on rare occasions:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    ChunkIndexes(processingList.Count, chunkSize),
    (interval) => {... code here ... });
```

The code after modification. Only the ParallelOptions parameter was added:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    ChunkIndexes(processingList.Count, chunkSize),
    new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount },
    (interval) => {... code here ... });
```

The original problem was observed only on Linux when running C# code compiled with.net core 2.1.